# RSFORMS thank you message show submission Id

Tags: joomla

In rsforms pro:

```
$thankYouMessage .= 'The number is inserted';
echo '$submissionId';
```

I have tried

```
$thankYouMessage .= 'The number '$submissionId' is inserted';
```

but it is not working. How do i display the submission id of the form I have submitted?

Comment: it should be `$thankYouMessage .= 'The number '.$submissionId.' is inserted';` You forgot to concatenate using dot operator.

Comment: Not working. It says The number is inserted', without showing the number.

Comment: Changed it to $thankYouMessage .= "Number $SubmissionId is inserted";
This worked, thank you.